# Access next.js static files inside docker & nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js

My `next.js` blog application is inside a docker container. The container is accessible on port 5000.

Inside `next.config`, we have `assetPrefix:'/blog'` but the browser is unable to load the assets (CSS, JS, ...)

Here's the current `nginx` config:

```
server {
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location /blog/_next/static/ {
            alias /usr/src/app/_next/;
            sendfile on;
            sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /blog/ {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The alias should be `/usr/src/app/_next/static/`. Try with something like

```
location /_next/static/ {
    alias /usr/src/app/_next/static/;
    try_files $uri =404;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
}
```